# Single activity vs multiple

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an app that has a MainActivity and has many ImageViews for hospitals, clinics, ... When pressing one of them it takes you to a new activity DisplayActivity that loads a pre-populated ListView. It seems illogical to have a separate activity for each one.

My question is can i use one activity to load different ListViews depending on which one was chosen. I know it can be done by XML, adding all ListViews in the DisplayActivity and make them visible/gone, but i want a more dynamic way, such as loading the desired ListView depending on the chosen item in the MainActivity.

This is how my Display activity currently looks like:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Display list of hospitals
        String[] doctors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hospitalList);         // Get array List ID
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, doctors);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hospitalListView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: make use of Fragments instead

Comment: You absolutely can populate the same `ListView` with different adapters, each of them fed with arbitrary data. When you change the 'ListView' adapter, the displayed data will change accordingly,

Comment: just replace fragment as per selection

Comment: fragments or switching out adapters, depending on various factors.  Although I wouldn't throw out the idea of multiple activities either, fragments can sometimes be a pain, sometimes the easiest way is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a convenience function:

```
void setListViewContent(@ArrayRes int arrayId) { 
       String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(arrayId);         // Get array List ID
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
       ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hospitalListView);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and then

```
setListViewContent(R.array.doctors);
setListViewContent(R.array.mcdonalds);
```

Comment: do i define this function is the MainActivity or the Display Activity?

Comment: On the activity where the `ListView` `R.id.hospitalListView` is. The function just populates the `ListView` with the array of your choice.